# Reducing an array into an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to turn the following object

```js
const order = {
  apple: 5,
  banana: 5,
  orange: 5
};
```

into the following object, with each key being assigned its index in the object as its value

```js
{
  apple: 0,
  banana: 1,
  orange: 2
}
```

This is the code I have but it's not working and I don't know why.

```js
const indices = Object.keys(order).reduce(
    (previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) =>
      (previousValue[currentValue] = currentIndex), {}
  );
TypeError: Cannot create property 'banana' on number '0'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Arrays have indexes. I'm not sure it's sensible to try and infer an ordering for attributes in an object (or dict/hashtable-like data structure), even if you can technically do it in some languages. Why do you want the 'index'?

Comment: There is no specification in JS that requires plain objects `{}` to have any ordering to keys - so things like `Object.keys` are not really deterministic (eg. you might not get the same thing back on on multiple calls). However, I have found in practice that the keys are generally returned in the order they were added. I would not stake any critical business functionality on this though as it could change any day without notice.

Comment: @RyanWheale This is just for a university project I'm building so I won't be worrying about things like that. Regardless, thank you for that insightful comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducer is expected to return the accumulator:

```js
const order = {
  apple: 5,
  banana: 5,
  orange: 5
};

const indices = Object.keys(order).reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    previousValue[currentValue] = currentIndex;
    return previousValue; // <-- this was missing in your attempt.
  }, {}
);

console.log(indices);
```

Comment: It would have been more precise to write "accumulated result". While here it is the same object, it could be something new, like if someone writes an own `join()` with `reduce()`, `[1,2,3].reduce((acc,item)=>acc+","+item)`, in every iteration a brand new string has to be created simply because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const order = {
    apple: 5,
    banana: 5,
    orange: 5,
};

const mapByIndex = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr, i) => {  
        return {
            ...acc,
            [curr]: i,
        };
    }, {});
};

console.log(mapByIndex(order)); // -> { apple: 0, banana: 1, orange: 2 }
```